# Sinatra: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby, sinatra

There is a code sample from *Sinatra: Up and Running*(Example 4-22). When I try to run it, the following result is given: `stack level too deep`.

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base 
  def self.inherited(sublass)
    super
    use sublass 
  end
  enable :logging 
end

# works with dynamically generated applications, too 
Sinatra.new ApplicationController do
  get '/' do
  "See the <a href='/example'>example</a>."
  end 
end
ApplicationController.run!
```

Indeed, this code looks wrong, because the new app extends AppController and when AppController `use` the app it will recur forever.

Then how to do this right?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class SinatraApp < Sinatra::Base
   get '/' do
     "See the <a href='/example'>example</a>."
   end
end

run SinatraApp.new
```

Comment: The trick here I want is to 'Automatically picking up subclasses as middleware'.